# How is GGH's bad basis public key safe from gram–schmidt orthogonalization?

Tags: public-key, lattice-crypto

I'm reading about lattice based cryptography. In my reading I read of gram–schmidt orthogonalization. Which allows for turning a bad basis into a good basis, or at least an orthogonal one.

Now I'm reading that in the GGH encryption scheme a good basis is used as private key and a bad basis is used as public key.

However my thought is that if the public key is known we can apply gram-schmidt orthogonalization to this bad basis to form a better one which would allow us to find the point that is being transferred.

How can this be safe? What am I missing in my thoughts?

---

It seems like that the problem is that with gram-schmidt we are having a $O(n!)$ computation because we need to do $n-1$ projections for every added dimensions. And as $O(n!)$ is worse than $O(2^n)$ we are still not in polynomial time with regards to our computation.

Comment: The output of the GSO process is a set of orthogonal vectors, but they are typically not a *lattice basis*. When applied to a “bad” basis, the orthogonalized vectors typically have rapidly decreasing lengths. This prevents them from successfully recovering the nearest lattice point to the ciphertext point.